# Group_concat MySQL function's equivalent in MS-SQL SERVER

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am looking for a function same [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) of mysql in T-SQL(SQL SERVER) or some functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have such group_concat of mysql in sql server, either you can use Stuff function or for xml path functionality to achiev

Comment: here is a **STUFF** based sample: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f09d4166-2030-41fe-b86e-392fbc94db53/tsql-equivalent-for-groupconcat-function